# Word for remembering everything you read

Tags: word-request

What is it called to remember everything you read, even if you read it once and years have passed and you can remember every sentence, phrase and word? Is it “normal” to do so?

Comment: You mean a verb or an expression meaning _remember everything you've read_? I don't think there's a separate entry in dictionaries for that, though people having such an incredible memory are those with **hyperthymesia**. Also see **eidetic memory**.

Comment: It’s not usual, obviously.

Answer (score 2):

The everyday term I know for this is *photographic memory* (M-W):

> [Definition of photographic memory](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/photographic%20memory)
>   : an unusual ability to remember things completely and exactly as they were seen, read, etc.

As the definition suggests, this term applies to more than just reading.

Comment: I'd go so far as to say that this term generally refers more to visual memory than to reading comprehension. But I'd also agree with you – this is probably the first term that will jump into the minds of most native speakers when it comes to answering this question.